# jQuery Image Slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, slideshow

There is a problem with my image sliding code. Whenever I press the "Next " or "Previous" button I must click 3 times until the button works, after doing this it works flawlessly. Here is my code:

```
    sliderInt=1;
    sliderNext=2;

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider>img#'+sliderInt).stop().fadeIn(500).delay(0);
    startSlider();
    });

    function startSlider(){
    count= $(".slider>img").size();

    loop=setInterval(function(){
    $(".slider>img#"+sliderInt).stop().fadeOut(500);

    if(sliderNext>count){
    sliderNext=1;
    }

    $(".slider>img#"+sliderNext).stop().fadeIn(500).delay(0);
    sliderNext++;
    sliderInt=sliderNext-1;
    },5000);
    }
    function prev(){
        stopLoop();
        $(".slider>img#"+sliderInt).stop().fadeOut(500);
        sliderInt--;
        if(sliderInt<1){
            sliderInt=count;
        }
        $(".slider>img#"+sliderInt).stop().fadeIn(500);
            startSlider();
        }
    function next(){
        stopLoop();
        $(".slider>img#"+sliderNext).stop().fadeOut(500);
        sliderNext++;
        if(sliderNext>count){
            sliderNext=1;
        }
        $(".slider>img#"+sliderNext).stop().fadeIn(500);
        startSlider();
        }
    function stopLoop(){
        window.clearInterval(loop);
    }
```

Comment: How does the HTML code look? If you set sliderNext = 0 in the beginning instead of 2, will this change anything?

Comment: Html code 
 <div class="slider" >
  <a href="#" id="prev" onclick="prev();return false;" >prev</a>
  <a href="#" id="next" onclick="next();return false;">next</a>
  <img id="1" src="1.jpg" border="0" alt="Firstphoto"class="imageslider"/>
  <img id="2" src="2.jpg" border="0"
  alt="Second photo" class="imageslider"/>
  <img id="3" src="3.jpg" border="0" alt="Third photo" class="imageslider">
 </div>

Comment: After changing sliderNext to = 0 the "Previous" button is working very well , but unfortunately the images after the first image has changed to blank because it's 0 now

Comment: Simply start with id="0" instead of id="1" in your html code :)

Comment: Can you post the edited code after changing it to 0 ? iam talking about the jQuery code !

Comment: i still can't figure it out :/

Comment: again the "Previous" started to glitch again after several tests with sliderNext=0 and html code Id's starting with 1

Comment: Okay, I think you've started with doing it wrong. I'll fix it and post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var index = 0;
var intervalID = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider img").hide();
    $(".slider img").first().addClass("active").show();

    startloop();
});

function startloop() {
    intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        next();
    }, 5000);
}

function stoploop() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}

function next() {     
    $(".slider img.active").removeClass("active").fadeOut(function() {
        index++;

        if(index == $(".slider img").length) {
            index = 0;
            $(this)
            $(".slider img").first().addClass("active").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(this).next().fadeIn().addClass("active");
        }
    });
}

function prev() {       
    $(".slider img.active").removeClass("active").fadeOut(function() {
        index--

        if(index < 0) {
            index = $(".slider img").length-1;
            $(this)
            $(".slider img").last().addClass("active").fadeIn();
        } else if(index == $(".slider img").length) {
            index = 0;
            $(this)
            $(".slider img").first().addClass("active").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(this).prev().fadeIn().addClass("active");
        }
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider" > 
        <a href="#" onclick="prev();stoploop();">prev</a> 
        <a href="#" onclick="next();stoploop();">next</a>
        <br>
        <img width="100px" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-7.jpg" title="1"/>
        <img width="100px" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-3.jpg" title="2"/> 
        <img width="100px" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-2.jpg" title="3"> 
        <img width="100px" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-5.jpg" title="4"> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the answer, so the stoploop() is being called onclick instead, since otherwise it will only loop once before stopping the loop.